# Maximum size of the value can be handled by EhCache

Tags: ehcache, distributed-caching, distributed-cache, ehcache-bigmemory

What is the maximum size of a value that can be held in EhCache in all the storage tiers(Memory Store, Off-heap Store, Disk Store) ?

My ultimate question is , does EhCache is suitable to cache large file streams?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ehcache does not have internal limits for storing very large values. The limit lives more on the heap memory your application can have. And that is because since Ehcache *ALWAYS* has an on heap tier and that values will be put in it when retrieved from the cache.

Ehcache is not designed to stream values from and to offheap or disk tiers, thus skipping the need to have enough heap to hold them.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. This is what I thought earlier and wanted someone who confirmed that.